# Sendmail server user unknown

Tags: sendmail, email

I'm trying to figure out the source of this problem. I have sendmail 8.13 on CentOS 5.9. I have virtusertable that I've used for a long time without trouble. Now, I have a problem with one email address in the virtusertable that only occurs when a specific person sends email to it.

The situation (using fake email addresses): virtusertable has the map "cwagner@cci.org cs@kainaw.com". Looking at /var/log/maillog, I can see hundreds of successes every day. Many of them come from the ghs.com company. Then, I got word that one person (and only one person) gets an error. When the sender is kayla@ghs.com, the /var/log/maillog has dsn=5.1.1 stat=User unknown. She can email cs@kainaw.com fine, but gets user unknown when emailing cwagner@cci.org.

How can this error occur for one and only one sender? I can't find any other error to work with to get to the source of the problem.

(responding to comment)
It has been verified that kayla is sending to the correct email address by checking the email address and by sending to her and having her hit reply. I also checked to see if, by chance, she is using a unicode character that looks like an ascii character. Finally, I cut and pasted the address from a word document on two computers. It worked on one and failed on hers.

Comment: Could you post full log entries for both cases? [ from= and to= entries]

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times when server says "user unknown" you should understand it literally.

Are you sure that your kayla@ghs.com sending e-mail to correct address? Maybe missing dot somewhere or non-latin characters?

Send a letter to kayla@ghs.com from cwagner@cci.org and ask her to push "reply" button. Not to write a new letter, not to copy-paste adress from "from" field. "reply"

Comment: See additional note added to question. I went to great lengths to ensure that the email address is correct.

Comment: Well, if her's is the only one computer having such problems, than you can be pretty sure problem's with her pc, and not with sendmail. How about antivirus checks, etc?

Comment: By the way, you can create some dummy mail account test@ghs.com and attach it to kaylas pc. On the other hand, try attaching mailbox kayla@ghs.com to pc, which is verified to be working correctly.